# Mocking and documentation in swift 2.2 and xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, testing, mocking

I am actually following a course on IOS development at my University but sadly a few interesting topics are not going to be thoroughly explained.
I have two main questions on those topics.

My first question is:

- How can someone mock a http request in his unit tests on xcode 7 when using a third party library like Alamofire or parse in his app?

My second question concerns documentation. I recently read that the code commenting  process for swift in xcode 7 had changed.

- I was wondering if there were some good tools to generate documentation based on the code commentaries a little bit like what javaDoc or apidoc do?

I thank you in advance for any explanation, tips, tutorials, or even just a guidance to some good ressources covering these two questions.

Have a good day and best regards,

Martin

Comment: For general advice on producing documentation, see http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/. At the end, he also talks about [Jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy), which can use the native documentation format to generate external documentation files.

Comment: For mocking network requests, consider https://yahooeng.tumblr.com/post/141143817861/using-nsurlprotocol-for-testing. Or you can use `XCTestExpectation` if you really want to test an asynchronous process such as a network request.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answers. I'll check out your links as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mocking Network Requests

You can use [OCMock](http://ocmock.org) or [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) to mock the network request. There's a lot info in the web.

Another alternative is to use a local HTTP server. For example, setting up a [Sinatra server](http://www.sinatrarb.com) will take just a few lines of code. This is useful, when you want to test more lower level details, for example whether your query parameters get correctly composed.

#### Swift Documentation

The tool chain supports a certain documentation syntax for Swift source code and playgrounds. This is documented here: [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497).

Here's an example how it looks like:

```
/**
 If `self` is `Success` returns the mapping function `f` applied to the
 value of `Success`. Otherwise, returns a new `Try` with the value of
 `Failure`.

 - parameter f: The maping function.
 - returns: A `Try<U>`.
 */
public func flatMap<U>(@noescape f: T -> Try<U>) -> Try<U> {
    switch self {
    case .Success(let value):
        return f(value)
    case .Failure(let error):
        return Try<U>(error: error)
    }
}
```

Source code from a third party library documented like this will enable any user of this framework to get quick help in their code when editing with Xcode.

In order to create HTML documents (and other types of documents) for your library you can use [Jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy). Jazzy is a command line tool, which creates HTML docs directly from the sources. In your project you can setup a "build task" which creates the documentation.

If you publish your library via [CocoaPods service](https://cocoapods.org), the documentation will be automatically created by CocoaPods service (using Jazzy for Swift and [AppleDoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) for Objective-C) and is available publicly. See here an example: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/3.3.1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will now dive into the different links you gave me.